# Error when refreshing child routes, Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm using PathLocationStrategy and the `<base href="/">` in index.html.
when I go into a child routes like product-detail if I try to refresh the page I get Error: Cannot match any routes, also if I go back and forward with browser.
Do I need to switch to HashLocationStrategy to handle refresh?

This is child routes.

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomerDetailComponent } from './index';

export const CustomerDetailRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'customer-detail/:code',
    component: CustomerDetailComponent
  },
];
```

And this is parent routes

```
import { DashboardComponent } from './index';

export const DashboardRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: DashboardComponent,
      children: [
        ...HomeRoutes,
        ...HotelRoutes,
        ...UserDetailRoutes,
        ...TicketTypeRoutes,
        ...TicketBlockRoutes,
        ...TransitCertificateRoutes,
        ...TemplateDetailRoutes,
        ...DepositReceiptRoutes,
        ...TemplateRoutes,
        ...LicensePlateDetailRoutes,
        ...DepositReceiptDetailRoutes,
        ...LicensePlatesRoutes,
        ...CustomerDetailRoutes,

      ]
    }
];
```

Comment: Does this happen locally as well as on the real server?

Comment: I can only try locally

Comment: Can you show where you're using `PathLocationStrategy`?

Comment: Isn't it the default strategy?, I only put `<base href="/">` in index

Comment: That's what I was after, ok then it should just work out of the box tbh.

Comment: What if you try putting `customer-detail/:code` as the parent route and have `path: ''` in the child route? That's what I have in all of my routes.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, how can I access to child with `path: ''`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149372/discussion-between-chrillewoodz-and-alessandro).

Comment: It could be that you're getting 404 from the server, not Angular. Check the networks tab what is returned for the request from server

Comment: @Maximus sorry I mean 404 in the console with following error: Error: Cannot match any routes, (404 it was because by default in app.routes I have `{ path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }`

Comment: so do you see `NotFoundComponent` rendered?

Comment: yes, only if I refresh a datail page that have this path `customer-detail/:code` and not a normal page with path like this: `customer`

Comment: How exactly do you got to the child route? `/dashboard/customer/detail/somecode`? Have you tried if it works with `HashLocationStrategy`?

Comment: in the url? http://localhost:4200/dashboard/customer-detail/customers/1... ok maybe I understand