# Documentation about different syntax in routes, Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using this theme: SB Admin Bootstrap 4 Angular 4.
But I see a different syntax in routes:

**App.routes**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  ...LoginRoutes,
  ...SignupRoutes
]
```

and in child routes
**SignupRoutes**

```
export const SignupRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
      path: 'signup',
      component: SignupComponent
    }
];
```

I never seen this syntax: [...Routes]
Is there some documentation/example

Comment: it's sread operator, read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) about it

Comment: I have some problem with it when I refreshing child page where path is  `path: 'depositReceipt-detail/:code'`...is it a good/new syntax? or I can use normal way? @Maximus

Comment: can you put the details in the question body and show what you're doing and rehprase the qeustion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140399/error-when-refreshing-child-routes-angular-4?noredirect=1#comment77253247_45140399